# How to compare two dictionaries in a python list?

Tags: python

**I'm having trouble iterating over values of the dictionaries in a python list.**

For eg:

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'score': 2}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}]
```

I want to compare the scores of both dictionaries and fetch the `id`
   of the highest score

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in `max` function with a key function of your definition:

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'score': 2}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}]

result = max(list1, key = lambda x : x['score'])['id']

print(result)
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and the key attribute to indicate you want to compare  the score:

```
from operator import itemgetter
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'score': 2}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}]

item = max(list1, key=itemgetter('score') )
# item is: {'id': 1, 'score': 2}
item['id']
```

result:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'score': 2}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}]
list1.sort(key=lambda x:x['score'],reverse=True)

sol = list1[0]['id']
print(sol)

# output 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list1 = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'calories': 137}, {'fruit': 'banana', 'calories': 254}, {'fruit': 'orange', 'calories': 488}]
>>> list1
[{'fruit': 'apple', 'calories': 137}, {'fruit': 'banana', 'calories': 254}, {'fruit': 'orange', 'calories': 488}]
>>> for dictionary in list1:
    print(dictionary)

{'fruit': 'apple', 'calories': 137}
{'fruit': 'banana', 'calories': 254}
{'fruit': 'orange', 'calories': 488}
>>> dictionary1 = list1[0]
>>> dictionary1
{'fruit': 'apple', 'calories': 137}
>>> for key in dictionary1:
    print(key)

fruit
calories
>>> for value in dictionary1.values():
    print(value)


apple
137
>>> for items in dictionary.items():
    print(items)


('fruit', 'orange')
('calories', 488)
```

Does this clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'score': 2}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}]
print(max(list1, key=lambda x: x['score'])['id'])
```

output:

```
1
```